# How to deploy NEXT.JS (MERN) in AWS?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, next.js

so i divided my project into 2 folders 
one is for frontend &
other is for backend
finally somehow my backend is working when I try it with aws-public-ip
but when I try to hit my frontend I am getting my code as output in screen

[my frontend output from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AmZX.jpg)
so I have a changed the entry point my index.js but its not rendering

Comment: Please include code as text, rather than a picture. Also, for tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: He tried to explain  that code is printed to UI :D

Comment: Can you share your folder structure and the file where you created your express server?

Comment: Actually, when i try to start my project in nginx server i am getting my code as output
but i want it to execute